# Multiple correlated SQL queries

Tags: sql, select, join, tuples, database-schema

I have a relational schema with three relations:

Relation **Product** with attributes `(pid, pname, color, weight, city)`

Relation **Project** with attributes `(jid, jname, city)`

Relation **Spj** with attributes `(sid, pid, jid, quantity)`

Each table has some tuples. This is not a realistic problem but an exercise on SQL queries. The query its result I need to find (which consists of 3 correlated queries) is the following:

```
SELECT p.pname
FROM product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT *
       FROM project j
       WHERE j.city = 'athens'
       AND NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT *
            FROM spj
            WHERE spj.pid = p.pid
            AND spj.jid = j.jid));
```

I started calculating the lower query thinking that this is a join between the 3 tables but even from the beginning (I started with joining Spj and Project tables) I ended up having a large table of 14 tuples. So, I think that I might be in the wrong direction.

I'm confused with the two tuple variables (product p, project j) and how to deal with those in general. Can somebody explain how to proceed this query step by step? Is it a "triple" join or not?

Comment: This is "*show me the products that are used on every Project in Athens*"  What exactly is your problem ?

Comment: They are called "correlated" subqueries, not "cascading". As @CharlesBretana mentioned, this is a relational division problem/query.

Comment: @CharlesBretana As I stated above, my problem is that I can't take this query step by step to understand that it's the division "show me the products that are used on every Project in Athens". Can you explain in more detail how did you analyze this query and how to retrieve the right tuples from this schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Show me the products that are used on **every** Project in Athens*

is equivalent to

*Show me the products where there is **no** project in Athens that does **not use** that product.*

This last sentence is ***exactly*** what the query above says.

```
SELECT p.pname                      -- Show me the products 
FROM product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS                    -- where there is **no** project 
  (SELECT *
   FROM project j
   WHERE j.city = 'athens'          -- in Athens
      AND NOT EXISTS                -- that does not use
          (SELECT *  FROM spj
           WHERE spj.pid = p.pid    -- that product
             AND spj.jid = j.jid))
```

Comment: OK, so we take each product (tuple of Product relation) at a time. For this product we take each project at a time and we check if for this project the city is Athens and the query SELECT *  FROM spj WHERE spj.pid = p.pid AND spj.jid = j.jid) returns non-empty relation. If there is at least one project satisfying this we add this product's name to the final result. Is that correct?

Comment: What the query says is exactly what it does... It finds all the products where there is no project in the city of Athens that is not using the product.  For each product, if it is used in Athens, on every project in Athens, it is included, if there is any single project in Athens that doesn't use it, it is excluded.

Comment: I got this but since I do not execute it on a computer I want to be sure that I can calculate the result myself since the tables I was given are relatively large. Thanks for your help!